# paypal recurring payment solution

Tags: php, paypal, recurring

I have been trying to figure out a solution which allows customer without paypal account and customer with credit card to subscribe. It is recurring payment.

I have used paypal payments standard but it doesn't allow customers to use the service without signing up with paypal.

I have signed up for payflow recurring payments. Which allows credit card users only but not paypal.

Now, I am looking at enhanced recurring payments standard which I am not sure going to help or not.

Just need help to point me in the right direction. Thanks for the help in advance.

https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/erp_overview

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced recurring payments would work, but it just ties the ability for people to use a credit card directly into the PayPal checkout pages.  They don't have to have a PayPal account, but it's not always obvious to buyers that that's the case and sometimes you'll lose sales because of it.

I would recommend going with Payments Pro, which it sounds like you already did since you said you signed up for PayFlow Recurring Payments..??  With Payments Pro and Recurring Billing as they call it, you can create your own credit card forms directly on your site pages and the user will have no idea PayPal is involved at all.  They'll just fill in the details directly without any redirection to PayPal.

Comment: Right now I have paypal payments advanced and payflow recurring payments setup for $5 + $10. If I use gateway that will need SSL because user will enter CC Info on the website.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like you have what you want then..??  I guess I'm confused about what you're asking.

Comment: We cannot overlook the effort on [PCI compliance](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/pci_compliant_solution).